# I cant not change this via Array.prototyp.applly when I use recursive function in vue metheds?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recursion, this

I want use recursive function to find child compoents in parent compoenent in vuejs.when I use Array.prototype.apply to change this to a child component, but this was not changed and also target to parent component? below is my code?

```
export default {
  name: "Z",
  mixins: [emitter],
  components: { A, B, C, Button },
  created() {
    this.$on("dispatch", e =>
      console.log("component Parent receive dispatch message: ", e)
    );
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      // this.broadcast("C", "broadcast", "broadcast message");
      this.recursiveBroadCast("C", "recursiveBroadcast", "recursive broadcast message");
    },
    recursiveBroadCast(componentName, eventName, params) {
      console.log('this', this)
      let children = this.$children
      let name
      for (let i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
        let child = children[i]
        name = child.$options.name
        if (name && name === componentName) {
          child.$emit.apply(child, [eventName, ...params])
          break
        } else {
          if (child.$children) {
            console.log('this', this)
            this.recursiveBroadCast.apply(child,[componentName,eventName].concat(params))
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
};
```

When I extract recursiveBroadCast outside of export default, this target child component corectly。Although I solved my problem，I dont konw why? who can help me solved my confusion.Thanks a lot.

```
function recursiveBroadCast (componentName, eventName, params) {
    let children = this.$children
    let name
    for (let i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
      let child = children[i]
      name = child.$options.name
      if (name && name === componentName) {
        child.$emit.apply(child, [eventName, ...params])
        break
      } else {
        if (child.$children) {
          recursiveBroadCast.apply(child,[componentName,eventName].concat(params))
        }
      }
    }
  }
export default {
  name: "Z",
  mixins: [emitter],
  components: { A, B, C, Button },
  created() {
    this.$on("dispatch", e =>
      console.log("component Parent receive dispatch message: ", e)
    );
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      // this.broadcast("C", "broadcast", "broadcast message");
      this.recursiveBroadCast("C", "recursiveBroadcast", "recursive broadcast message");
    },
    recursiveBroadCast(componentName, eventName, params) {
      recursiveBroadCast.apply(this,[componentName, eventName, params] )
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: After the first `apply` the this object is the child object and when runs `this.recursiveBroadCast.apply` again maybe don’t has the `.recursiveBroadCast`. Which error gives you?

Comment: no error, just call stack overflow.